# Can´t turn object into string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, data-transform

I'm working with a very simple dataframe. It has just one feature but that feature seems to appear as a float even though it saiys it is a object it gives me error when i try to use it as a string.

```
                       Id
0                  4853.0
1                  4853.0
2                 23430.0
3                 40704.0
4                 23298.0
5                  6246.0
6                  7345.0
```

When i do dtypes it devolves:

```
actor_identity_id    float64  dtype: object
```

So i did:

df['Id'] = df['Id'].astype(str)

But it doesn't do anything because later i try to use it as a string:

```
if df['Id'].endswith('.0'):
    url = df['Id'][:-2]
```

To get rid of the end of the string and it devolves the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

It gives the same error when i use rsplit.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or another cleaner way, using `apply`:

```
df['Id']=df['Id'].apply(lambda x: x[:-2] if x.endswith('.0') else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

To point out your problem, currently you're having a `Series` and expecting it to have an attribute `endswith` with is an attribute of `string`. Hence, you should do `df['Id'].str.endswith('.0')`.

However, better implement the same using `apply` function. Note, when using lambda you take one element at a time and hence no use of `str` as written by @U9-Forward.

Comment: There is a difference in telling where OP is getting wrong. It's important to highlight where to use `str` and where not. May be if you have added that, I wouldn't have to do it.

Comment: Well, still copying my answer.

Comment: Oh well. Gave your reference. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that it will always contain .0 at end then instead you could use a simple way

```
df['id']=df['id'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

Since it is id column and i guess it can't be float value
Edit:

If you are not sure then

```
df['id']=df['id'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x-int(x)==0)
```